# Misunderstanding with async maybe? console log not printing in .then()

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app and in that app I have a componentdidmount function that looks roughly like this : (redacted non essential info) (description at the bottom)

```js
import '../css/options2.css'
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify'

import SearchSaved from './options2Components/SearchSaved.js'
import SavedList from './options2Components/SavedList.js'

import  { configureStore }  from './store';
import { addToSaved } from './actions/saved-items.js';

const store = configureStore();


export default class Options2 extends React.Component {
     componentDidMount() {

       //Here I want to grab the user session and id with an async funct

       Auth.currentSession()
      .then((data) => {

       //I attempt to log data in order to check values at given a given time

        console.log(data, "data")
        let user =  data.username
        return user
        console.log(user)
        fetch("fetchToAPI/get", {
          credentials: 'same-origin',
          method: 'GET',
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'user': user }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
        .then(responseData => {

         // if the data is acquired log it some more and map it out 

          console.log(responseData, "hi")
          var dataMapped = responseData.map(data => ({
            associatedMp3: data.associatedMp3,
            saveId: data.saveId,
            textValue: data.text,
            title: data.title,
            user: data.user,
            voiceSelected: data.voiceSelected,
            createdAt: data.createdAt
          }));

          //  store.dispatch(addToSaved({dataMapped}))
          //  console.log(dataMapped)

        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
       })
       .catch(() => {
         console.log('not auth')
       })
  }

  // Redacted render call
```

Non of my console logs are printing! I tried remaking it with async await and only became more confused. The documentation is pretty clear but I still do not know why the logs wont print. Seems like the error logs will if there is an error but on success it seems like nothing happened.

Everything is configured properly, it seems to just be the way I am handling the situation that is wrong.

Would be cool if someone can explain two things: 
How can I get the console logs to print
and 
Is my code poorly written for what I am trying to achieve?

I am still relatively new at asking questions if there is anything you need to know let me know!

**EDIT**

Function without any extra requests just to console log data from currentSession returns no console log statements

```js
componentDidMount() {
       console.log("hello")
       //Here I want to grab the user session and id with an async funct

       Auth.currentSession()
      .then((data) => {

       //I attempt to log data in order to check values at given a given time

        console.log(data, "data")
        let userId =  data.username
        console.log(userId)
       })
       .catch((err) => {
         console.log(err)
       })
  }
```

Comment: I don't see `async` in here at all. `.catch()` and `.then()` are for promises. Now async, does create a promise in ES6 but you can't mix the syntax quite like this. I suggest reading up on the difference - check out this tutorial: https://javascript.info/async

Comment: I apologize, I was not trying to say I'm using async await, but the actual functionality is asynchronous, correct? I might be misunderstanding how to return console logs in this case.

Comment: If you put a console log just inside `componentDidMount()` but before `Auth.currentSession()` do you see it print to the console? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Even the first log does not work? This one: `console.log(data, "data")` ? After that, you have an early `return` in your code. `return user`. So after this point, your code does not work for the fetch part.

Comment: So I had an error that wasnt being caught because my last catch statement wasn't logging the error. After that It is saying Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. Must be because the fetch is returning 401. So as long as the fetch returns unauthorized I won't be able to see anything in the then statement I'm guessing? I just thought I might get the console logs from outside that statement too, but maybe not because it calls back the error before finish the function?

Comment: And yeah I took that return user out that was my bad @devserkan

Comment: So, I guess my main question now is how could I log data from Auth.currentSession() to see what it has? I tried to comment everything out so I'm only checking the first then() and catch() but I still see no console logs.

Comment: What is the first log you see? What does the log show in your first `.then` method? Put a `console.log` in the first `.then` method of fetch. Can you see a response?

Comment: Are you sure that `currentSession` returns a promise? `Auth.currentSession() returns a CognitoUserSession object which contains JWT accessToken, idToken, and refreshToken`. [Via](https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/media/authentication_guide.html).

Comment: This shouldn't be possible. There might be a typo or you can't render your component where you are rendering it. Put a `console.log` in the `render` method. Though, this is just to be sure since if a component mounts first `render` fires then for the last thing `componenDidMount` is called. So, if there isn't a typo or something else this is not possible. Oops, I think you deleted your last comment :)

Comment: Yes it returns a promise, I should be able to figure something out from here. My main issue, the filter in the console was silencing errors and I must of typed a letter that allows a lot of other logs to pour in from my other components but not this one. Thank you for walking through this with me but I think that I am all set now that I can see the logs printing. *facepalm*